# DB Design and Data Retrieval from a heavy table

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, query-optimization, data-retrieval

I have a requirement to have 612 columns in my database table. The # of columns as per data type are:

BigInt – 150 (PositionCol1, PositionCol2…………PositionCol150)

Int - 5

SmallInt – 5

Date – 150 (SourceDateCol1, SourceDate2,………….SourceDate150)

DateTime – 2

Varchar(2000) – 150 (FormulaCol1, FormulaCol2………………FormulaCol150)

Bit – 150 (IsActive1, IsActive2,……………….IsActive150)

When user does the import for first time the data gets stored in PositionCol1, SourceDateCol1, FormulaCol1, IsActiveCol1, etc. (other datetime, Int, Smallint columns).

When user does the import for second time the data gets stored in PositionCol2, SourceDateCol2, FormulaCol2, IsActiveCol2, etc. (other datetime, Int, Smallint columns)….. so and so on.

There is a ProjectID column in the table for which data is being imported.

Before starting the import process, user maps the excel column names with the database column names (PositionCol1, SourceDateCol1, FormulaCol1, IsActiveCol1) and this mapping get stored in a separate table; so that when retrieved data can be shown under these mapping column names instead of DB column names. E.g.

PositionCol1 may be mapped to SAPDATA

SourceDateCol1 may be mapped to SAPDATE

FormulaCol1 may be mapped to SAPFORMULA

IsActiveCol1 may be mapped to SAPISACTIVE

40,000 rows will be added in this table every day, my questions is that will the SQL be able to handle the load of that much of data in the long run?

Most of the times, a row will have data in about 200-300 columns; in the worst case it’ll have data in all of the 612 columns. Keeping in view this point, shall I make some changes in the design to avoid any future performance issues? If so, please suggest what could be done?

If I stick to my current design, what points I should take care of, apart from Indexing, to have optimal performance while retrieving the data from this huge table?

If I need to retrieve data of a particular entity e.g. SAPDATA, I’ll have to go to my mapping table, get the database column name against SAPDATA i.e. PositionCol1 in this case; and retrieve it. But, in that way, I’ll have to write dynamic queries. Is there any other better way?

Answer (score 0):

Don't stick with your current design. Your repeating groups are unweildy and self limiting... What happens when somebody uploads 151 times? Normalise this table so that you have one of each type per row rather than 150. You won't need mapping this way as you can select SAPDATA from the positioncol without worring if it is 1-150.

You probably want a PROJECTS table with an ID, a PROJECT_UPLOADS table with an ID and an FK to the PROJECTS table. This table would have Position, SourceDate, Formula and IsActive given your use-case above.

Then you could do things like

select p.name, pu.position from PROJECTS p inner join PROJECT_UPLOADS pu on pu.projectid = p.id WHERE pu.position = 'SAPDATA'

etc.

Comment: I have already burnt my fingers with the suggested design as the rows have to be pivoted into columns for a number of columns with the help of dynamic queries. So, If you have lods of data then this design does not work.

Comment: And the columns are fixed and they are not going to increase. Also, as the data is stored in the same way as I want to retreive, so data retreival is quite fast because it does not need to do the pivot thing.

Comment: When you say "40,000 rows a day", how many of those will be "active"? Is this historical data? You can partition data in most modern RDBMSs which would minimise impact on performance (depending on how your queries are structured). You may want to consider a data warehousing solution as a) it will help you with the structure you suggest (i.e. keep your queries simple and quick) and b) reduce load on the live system. But I don't really understand your use-case well enough to be able to make a solid recommendation.

Comment: Can someone please provide some suggestions/comments?

Comment: Exactly Jeff.. That's what I am thinking a) To keep the queries simple and quick with the current design and then reduce the load on live system afterwards by taking historical tables. I needed the confirmation from the experts. Can you please tell what did not you understand from the given use case?

Comment: How many rows are current, i.e. can you archive off every x hours/days/weeks. Your reporting, is it mainly for historical purposes or does it have to be 100% live data? How is it being inserted/updated into in the live database?

Comment: All 40000 rows will be current initally and the data in this table can be archived off every 4 weeks. Data will be inserted through excel imports and through manual inputs as well. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Can someone please provide suggestions/comments on that?

Comment: This has gone beyond being able to discuss in small comment boxes. Feel free to invite me to chat about it.

Comment: How can i invite you on chat?