# Performance Issues with DB Design and Heavy Data

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, query-optimization, database-performance

I asked the following question regarding DB Design and Performance issue in my application today.

[DB Design and Data Retrieval from a heavy table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10846340/db-design-and-data-retrieval-from-a-heavy-table/10846391#comment14126017_10846391)

But, could not get much replies on that. I don't know, I may not have explained the question properly. Now, I have re-defined my question, hoping to get some suggestion from the experts.

I am facing performance issues while selecting data from a particular table. The business logic of the application is as following:
I have a number of import processes which result in creating pivot columns under their parent column names while showing them to the user. As the columns get pivoted, system takes time to convert rows into columns which results in slow performance.
The database tables related to this functionality are as following:
There can be N number of clients. CLT_Clients table stores client information.

There can be N number of projects associated to a client. PRJ_Projects table stores project information and a link to the client.

There can be N number of listings associated to a project. PRJ_Listings table stores listing information and a link to the project.

There can be N number of source entities associated to a listing. ST_Entities table stores source entity information and a link to the listing.

This source entity is the actual import that contains the InvestorID, position values, source date, active and formula status.

```
The name of the import e.g. L1Entity1 is stored in ST_Entities table alongwith ID field i.e. EntityID
InvestorID, Position, Source Date, Active and Formula values get stored in ST_Positions table
```

Database Diagram
[image: DB Design]

Data need to be view as following:
[image: Data View]

With this design I’m able to handle N number of imports because the Position, Source Date, IsActive, Formula columns get Pivoted.

The problem that I’m facing with this design is that the system performs very slow when it has to select data for more than 10-12 source entities, and the requirement is to show about 150 source entities. Because data is not stored row wise and I need to show it column wise, hence dynamic queries are written to pivot these columns which takes long.

**Ques 1:** Please comment/suggest on my current database design if it’s correct or need to be changed with the new design by taking 150 columns each for Position, Source Date, IsActive, Formula; In this new way data will already be stored in the way I need to retrieve in i.e. I’ll not have to pivot/unpivot it. But the downside is:

a) There are going to be more than 600 columns in this table?

b) There will be limit i.e. 150 on the source entities.

**Ques 2:** If I need to stick to my current, what can be done to improve the performance?

Please see below the indexing and Pivot method information:

Regarding indexes in Position table, I also have taken ProjectID field with clustered index as the data is selected from Position table either on the basis of ProjectID OR EntityID.

Whenever EntityID is used to select data from Position table, it's always used in JOIN. And Whenever ProjectID is used to select data from this table, it's always used in WHERE.

Point to notice here is that I have a Clustered index on ProjectID but I have not taken any index on Pivoted column OR EntityID. Is there any room for improvement here?

Pivoting Method used:

```
Example 1:

'Select * From
(
    Select DD.InvestorID,Cast(1 As Bit) As IsDSInvestor,DD.Position,
    Case DD.ProjectID
    When ' + CAST(@ProjectID AS VARCHAR) +' Then DE.SourceName 
    Else ''' + @PPDeliveryDate + '''+DE.SourceName
    End As SourceName
    From DE_PositionData DD
    Inner Join DE_DataEntities DE ON DE.EntityID=DD.EntityID
    Where DD.ProjectID IN (' + CAST(@ProjectID AS VARCHAR) +',' + CAST(@PreviousProjectID AS VARCHAR) +') AND InvestorID IS NOT NULL

) IDD
Pivot
(
    max(Position) for SourceName in ('+ @DataColumns+')
) as p1'
```

Example2:

```
'Select * From
    (
        Select DD.InvestorID As DSSOFID,Cast(1 As Bit) As IsActiveInvestor,
        Case ST.SourceTypeCode
            When ''RSH'' Then Cast(IsNull(DD.IsActive,0) As Int)
            Else Cast(IsNull(DD.IsActive,1) As Int) 
        End As IsActive,
        ''~''+DE.SourceName As ActiveSourceName
        From DE_DataEntities DE
        Left Join DE_PositionData DD ON DE.EntityID=DD.EntityID
        Left Join 
        (
            Select * From #DataSources
            Where ProjectID=' + CAST(@ProjectID AS VARCHAR) +'
        ) ST ON ST.ESourceID=DE.ESourceID
        Where DE.ProjectID=' + CAST(@ProjectID AS VARCHAR) +' AND ST.SourceTypeCode NOT IN (''PBC'',''EBL'',''REG'')
        AND InvestorID IS NOT NULL

    ) IDD
    Pivot
    (
        Max(IsActive) for ActiveSourceName in ('+ @DataColumns+')
    ) As p1'
```

Comment: I see no problem with your current schema for OLTP. It seems to be the most appropriate for what you are after. I think your report layout is questionable though. What are you using to display your data? Excel, SSRS, Web Forms, etc. Either way I think 600 columns of data in a report is far too much for anyone to digest. Perhaps if you could elaborate on your reporting medium a better report structure could be suggested. You may also want to look into warehousing data and using SSAS.

Comment: Gareth, thanks for the quick response. The data needs to be displayed in a grid only in the Winform, where user will be able to make changes in it. This 600 figure is the worst case scenario; Generally there will about 150-200 columns in the grid.

Comment: If it is being done on Winforms would the best solution not to be having a hierarchical form structure, so the user can select a client, to get a view of Projects, by clicking on a project they can then edit project details and see all associated Listings. By clicking on a listing they can then edit the listing, and see all positions? It is personal preference I suppose, but I would rather develop this structure, and prefer it as a user. You can also retrieve data on demand, and reduce the amout of data retrieved from the database at any one time.

Comment: Sorry GarethD, i could not follow you. Do you agree with the DB Design I presented OR you have a different thought? If different, can you please elaborate?

Comment: To summarise, I agree with your database design, but I think displaying the data on a form with 100's of columns is a bad idea. You have relational data so you should display it as such. That is to say, you probably don't need to display every bit of data on one form, start at the top level, and expand from there. So one form to show all clients, then a client form that shows client details plus all projects, then another form that shows one project and all listings etc.

Comment: If you really do need to display all data on one form have a separate reporting table that stores this data in this format that is maintained by daily jobs. Or like I said, look at SQL-Server Analysis Services. Your data structure seems ideally suited to storing in a cube for OLAP.

Comment: @Gareth, the data view that i presented above is just to show you how that data is laid down. But actually, in the grid, I just need to show only one project's data. I got +ve views about my DB Design on all of the forums. Now, I need to be sure about the Indexes and Pivot method used. Can you please provide your comments on them.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following.

You should store your data in the normalized format.  You should be able to set up indexes to make the pivoting of the data go faster.  If you post the actual query that you are using for pivoting, we might be able to help.

There are many reasons you want to store the data this way:

- Flexibility in the number of repeating blocks
- Many databases have limits on the number of columns or total width of a table.  You don't want your design to approach those limits.
- You may want additional information on each block.  I always include CreatedBy and CreatedAt columns in my tables, and you would want this per block.
- You have additional flexibility in summarization.
- Adding/removing intermediate values is cumbersome.

That said, the pivoted table has one key advantage:  it is what users want to see.  If your data is updated only once per day, then you should create a reporting table with the pivot.

If your data is updated incrementally throughout the day, then you can set up triggers (or stored procedure code) to update the base tables and the reporting summary.

But as I said earlier, you should ask another question is the particular method you are using for pivoting.  Perhaps we can improve the performance there.

Comment: I have edited my question and added the information regarding indexes and Pivot method used.

Comment: Gordon, can you please provide your viewpoint on the Pivot method and Index used?

Comment: Is EntityId a primary key on DE_PositionData?  Having this as a primary key with an index on DE_DataEntities would probably greatly help the query.

Comment: ListingID is the clustered index in DE_DataEntities and EntityID is the primary key and a non-clustered index. Regarding DE_PositionData, ProjectID is the clustered index and DataID is the primary key, there is no Index on EntityID in this table. Please suggest if any changes are required?